# Remove dictionary in list Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two dictionaries: `output` contains a main dataset including a list of relevant items and `output_historical` contains a subset of the items in the list of `output`.

I would like to add the value of the `output_historical` keys to the `output` values, but delete the whole list-item if there is no value in `output_historical`. In the over-simplified example below, `{'test2': {'info': '1'}}` should be deleted from `output`.

```
output_historical = [
    {
        'test1': {'result': 0}, 
        'test3': {'result': 3}
    }
]
output = [
    {'tests': 
         [
             {'test1': {'info': '0'}}, 
             {'test2': {'info': '1'}}, 
             {'test3': {'info': '2'}}
         ]
    }
]

for item in output:
    for testobject in item["tests"]:
        for test in testobject.copy():
            if test in output_historical[0]:
                print("add", test)
                testobject[test]["result"] = output_historical[0][test]["result"]
            else:
                print("del", test)
                # del ??
print(output)
# Expected output: [{'tests': [{'test1': {'info': '0', 'result': 0}}, {'test2': {'info': '1'}}, {'test3': {'info': '2', 'result': 3}}]}]
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use `del testobject[test]`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, that results in `[{'tests': [{'test1': {'info': '0', 'result': 0}}, {}, {'test3': {'info': '2', 'result': 3}}]}]`, including ```{},```.

Comment: Can the dictionaries inside `tests` have more than one element?

Comment: @Barmar Yes and they should be kept unchanged.

Comment: Can you show examples with multiple dictionaries and the intended result? Do you remove the entire dictionary if any of the keys are missing from `output_historical`? Or just if all the keys are missing? Or you only remove the missing keys, and remove the entire dictionary if that result is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `remove()` method.

Since you shouldn't remove from a list that you're iterating over, you should iterate over a copy of the list. I don't think you need to make a copy of `testobject`, since you're never adding or removing anything in that dictionary.

```
for item in output:
    for testobject in item["tests"].copy():
        for test in testobject:
            if test in output_historical[0]:
                print("add", test)
                testobject[test]["result"] = output_historical[0][test]["result"]
            else:
                print("del", test)
                item["tests"].remove(testobject)
                break
```